# Covariant derivative of 1-form

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I use the 3 of Proposition 1.27 to compute equality above red line. 
$\nabla_X(dx^j\otimes\partial_i)=
\nabla_X(dx^j)\otimes\partial_i+
dx^j\otimes\nabla_X(\partial_i)$.

Then, how to get the red line equality ?

And,How use $\nabla_X(tr(dx^j\otimes\partial_i))=0$ 
to get $\nabla_X(dx^j\otimes\partial_i)=0$ ?

> [image]
>
> [image]

Comment: Hi, I am learning Riemannian Geometry recently and I like the statement of the book you referenced, can you please tell me the name of the book? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not true that $\nabla_X({\rm tr}(dx^j\otimes\partial_i))=0$ implies $\nabla_X(dx^j\otimes\partial_i)=0$; indeed this latter equation is false for most coordinate systems. Remember that you don't need to show $$\nabla_X dx^j \otimes \partial_i = -dx^j \otimes \nabla_X \partial_i,$$ but only the contracted version

$$(\nabla_X dx^j) (\partial_i) = -dx^j (\nabla_X \partial_i).$$ (Remember that ${\rm tr} (\omega \otimes X) = \omega(X)$.)

Thus you can simply take the trace of your equation $$\nabla_X(dx^j\otimes\partial_i)=
\nabla_X(dx^j)\otimes\partial_i+
dx^j\otimes\nabla_X(\partial_i)$$ and use property 4 to show the LHS is zero.